# BlazeDS / Tomcat Configuration

Tags: tomcat, configuration, blazeds

I'm new to blazeDS/Tomcat..

I made a Flex application that communicates with a blazeDS server...
Everything works good, I have only one problem, the `console app` is accessible from everywhere (local network, internet), I'd like to secure it, with password or something else...

I have not edited any tomcat/blazeDS file, except remoting.xml to setting up my app destination...
There are no users...

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the console application from a production environment (just delete ds-console.war from tomcat/webapps/). If you still want to keep it you can find a lot of articles on internet about how to secure an war application. Some examples: [Basic authentication](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html), [Secure authentication](http://www.indicthreads.com/1443/setting-up-secure-web-authentication-in-tomcat/).